# Should similarity matrix must always be converted into a dissimilarity matrix for hierarchical clustering?

Tags: matrix, correlation, similarity, hierarchical-clustering

Background

Hi all, I need some clarification on my approach if it's correct or not. I have a matrix (*M_ij*) with user ratings of images. The users (*i*) are on the horizontal axis and the images (*j*) are on the vertical axis. The cell *ij* has the ratings given by the user. These ratings are on a discrete scale from (1-5). This is a sparse matrix since each user did not rate all the images but rather the subset of images.

My Approach

I found a correlation matrix of users. Since I had 756 users, the resulting correlation matrix had the dimensions 756 x 756. To cluster these users based on how similar their ratings were, I converted this matrix to a dissimilarity matrix doing $2 \times \sqrt{1 - s}$ to get $d$, the correlation distance (based on https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/36158). Then I used the ward's method by using $d$ as the distance metric to perform hierarchical clustering.

My Unclarities:

- While the above approach seems valid, I do not understand why a
  correlation matrix must be converted to a distance matrix for
  clustering. I read this [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/165194/using-correlation-as-distance-metric-for-hierarchical-clustering), but I could not understand that if
  correlation coefficients can be treated as points, then why go
  through the trouble of converting it into a distance matrix for clustering?
- What could be the reasons why this approach may be wrong?
- Should I have not used the Ward method and had used any other method for hierarchical clustering using $d$?
- Based on the geometrical properties ([as mentioned here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/36158)) of a positive semi-definite matrix, it must not have any negative eigenvalues. However, in my case, the correlation matrix had several negative eigenvalues, but yet I calculated $d$ from it. Is it wrong? or the resulting $d$ matrix was partially valid?

Thank you in advance :)

P.S.: Duplicate of [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/616705/388667)